# Using CookieContainer with NSUrlSessionHandler

Tags: xamarin.ios

Within a Xamarin app I'm trying to move from using `ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler` to using `NSUrlSessionHandler` but I've hit a road block around the use of `CookieContainer` the code I've tried to write is:

```
var httpHandler = new NSUrlSessionHandler();
httpHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
httpHandler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

return new HttpClient(httpHandler);
```

This doesn't compile because `NSUrlSessionHandler` doesn't have a `CookieContainer` property.

Is it possible to achieve something like this where we set the cookies for the handler to use?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up extending the nsurlSessionHandler and implementing my cookieLogic.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;
using Foundation;
using Appname.Mobile;
using Appname.Mobile.Services;

namespace Appname.Mobile.iOS
{
    [Preserve]
    public class CustomMessageHandler : NSUrlSessionHandler
    {
        static ICookieStorageService CookiesService { get; set; }
        static CookieContainer Container { get; set; }

        public KDSHttpClientHandler()
        {
            CookiesService = App.Container.Resolve<ICookieStorageService>();
        }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (CookiesService != null)
        {
            Container = CookiesService.GenerateCookieContainer(request.RequestUri);
            CookiesService.ApplyRecentCookie(Container, request);
        }

        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (CookiesService != null)
        {
            var cookieHeaders = result.Headers.Where(h => h.Key.Equals("Set-Cookie", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();

            foreach (var header in cookieHeaders)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (header.Value != null)
                    {
                        var cookieParts = header.Value.First().Split(';');
                        var cookieValue = cookieParts[0].Split('=');
                        Container.Add(new Cookie(cookieValue[0], cookieValue[1], "/", request.RequestUri.GetBaseDomain()));
                        CookiesService.UpdateCookies(Container, request.RequestUri);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    App.Logger.Error("CustomMessageHandler.SendAsync.CookieContainer", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HttpClientHandler](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs) and [NSUrlSessionHandler](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs) both subclass [HttpMessageHandler](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs) and implement the `SendAsync()` method. The `CookieContainer` is a construct belonging only in HttpClientHandler and as you've found doesn't exist in `NSUrlSessionHandler`.

In Xamarin.iOS you can work directly with [NSHttpCookieStore](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSHttpCookieStorage/), a singleton with a shared cookie store automatically shared with NSUrlSessionHandler. You could look through the `SetCookie` method in the NSHttpCookieStorage documentation.

Example:

```
{
    foreach (var cookie in NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Name: {cookie.Name}, Path: {cookie.Path}"
    }
}
```